# Openshift Jenkins is cancelling Item

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have a Free Openshift Account with two gears (wildfly & jenkins) in use and one empty ready for the build-job(wildfly-bldr). One gear running wildfly8 with a MySQL db, phpMyAdmin and a jenkins cartridge. This one works fine. The second gear is the jenkins server. This one is supposed to build my *.war and deploy it. It was all once running just fine. After a dozen of builds out of the blue it stopped working. My first guess was the gear would be to small. But looking at the quota on my first gear it must be some other problem.

```
quota -s

Disk quotas for user  (uid 2606): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
                   737M       0   1024M            7214       0   80000
```

I then tried to monitor the build log:

```
$ rhc tail jenkins
Sep 30, 2014 4:04:54 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud reloadConfig
INFO: Reload ResponseCode: 200
Sep 30, 2014 4:04:54 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud reloadConfig
INFO: Config reload result: 
Sep 30, 2014 4:04:54 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave <init>
INFO: Creating slave with 15mins time-to-live
Sep 30, 2014 4:04:54 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave createApp
INFO: Creating builder application wildfly-wildfly-8 yyybldr xxx of size small ...
Sep 30, 2014 4:04:54 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting POST with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/applications?include=cartridges
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:50 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave createApp
INFO: Stopping application on builder gear ...
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:50 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting POST with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/application/yyybldr/events
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:53 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave connect
INFO: Connecting to slave yyybldr...
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:53 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting GET with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/application/yyybldr/gear_groups
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:53 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave connect
INFO: Established UUID = 542b0ce65973ca6ca60000ea
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:58 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting GET with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/application/yyybldr/gear_groups
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:58 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud **provision**
**WARNING: Caught java.io.IOException: Unable to find application url for yyybldr. Will retry 4 more times before canceling build.**
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud getSlaves
INFO: Didn't find existing slave for: yyybldr
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave <init>
INFO: Creating slave with 15mins time-to-live
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputer <init>
INFO: Creating Computer
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Launching slave...
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave connect
INFO: Connecting to slave yyybldr...
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting GET with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/application/yyybldr/gear_groups
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud getSlave
INFO: slaveExists yyybldryyybldr
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud builderExists
INFO: Capacity remaining - checking for existing type...
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud builderExists
INFO: Found an existing builder.  Not provisioning...
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provisionSlave
INFO: Slave exists. Not provisioning
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provision
INFO: Provisioned 0 new nodes
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
INFO: Cancelling Item 
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:03 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
WARNING: Build yyy-build yyybldrhas been canceled
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:04 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave connect
INFO: Established UUID = 542b0ce65973ca6ca60000ea
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:09 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Checking availability of computer hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftSlave@8ceaea0f
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:09 PM com.openshift.internal.client.RestService request
INFO: Requesting GET with protocol 1.2 on https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/xxx/application/yyybldr/gear_groups
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:09 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Checking SSH access to application yyybldr-xxx.rhcloud.com
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:09 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Connecting via SSH '542b0ce65973ca6ca60000ea' 'yyybldr-xxx.rhcloud.com' '/var/lib/openshift/53ef69ac5973ca352200032c/app-root/data/.ssh/jenkins_id_rsa'
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:10 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Sep 30, 2014 4:08:10 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Exec mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins && cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins && rm -f slave.jar && wget -q --no-check-certificate https://jenkins-xxx.rhcloud.com/jnlpJars/slave.jar
```

I cant see why the item is being canceled. So the build actually never gets into progress.

Any Idea what is causing the jenkins server to cancel the build job?

It seems this is where it starts to go wrong:

```
Sep 30, 2014 4:07:58 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud **provision**
**WARNING: Caught java.io.IOException: Unable to find application url for yyybldr. Will retry 4 more times before canceling build.**
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have any free gears to create the builder gear?

Comment: Yes, that was also what I thought, but I have a free gear. one for the app, one for jenkins and one for the actual build.

Comment: Try restarting your Jenkins gear and see if that resolves it.